# Yii - Get data from Model

Tags: php, yii

I have the following in my controller:

```
public function actionIndex() {
  $userID = Yii::app()->user->getId();
  $arNotifs = Notification::model()->getNotificationsByUserId($userID);

  $this->render('index', array("arNotifications"=>$arNotifs, "userID"=>$userID));
}
```

I have the following in a file called notification.php in my models:

```
class Notification extends CActiveRecord {
  // ------ BUNCH OF STUFF
  public function getNotificationsByUserId($userId) {
    $userId = (int) $userId;        
    $query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
    $query->select('n.id, n.title, n.content, n.updated');
    $query->from('hr4_notification_x_user nxu');
    $query->join('hr4_notification n', 'nxu.notification = n.id');
    $query->where('nxu.user=:userId', array(':userId' => $userId);
    return $query->queryAll();
  }
  // ------ MORE STUFF
}
```

When I rem out the line

```
$arNotifs = Notification::model()->getNotificationsByUserId($userID);
```

and replace it with a static value it works fine.  It seems that in my noob ways I am missing some vital step.  The controller seems to have no idea what Notification is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you have when this line is set?

Comment: In the end it turns out I was missing a closing paren: $query->where('nxu.user=:userId', array(':userId' => $userId); dumb dumb dumb dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the most elegant way to get your notifications on the controller would be something like:

```
$arNotifs = Yii::app()->user->model->notifications;
```

To achieve such, you might need to implement a getModel() method on your class that extends CWebUser. That method would return an instance of an user that extends CActiveRecord. Then your user model can have a relations() method, like the following:

```
class UserModel extends CActiveRecord {
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'notifications' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Notification', 'user'),
        );
    }
}
```

This will prevent you from writing that query and will make things more clear (on both, models and controller). If you will, read a bit about [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use the Notification model like this.
You can instantiate it with `$notification = new Notification();`
and then do a `$notification->getNotificationsByUserId($userID);`

However this would be not very good. I would move the notification code from the model to the User model.
This was you dont even need to pass the user ID.
Or maybe even better, if you make a component out of `Notification` and use it as a service.

Comment: False, the way he use it is totally fine. You can do Notification::model()->getNotificationsByUserId($userID). The model() method will instantiate a new object of this class. This is kind of the singleton pattern

Comment: Yes you're right. I should have said 'You should not use the model like this.'

Comment: Thanks guys, it looks like it is actually something within getNotificationsByUserId that is actually halting the execution.

Comment: Every damn time it's something stupid like a missing paren and I find it right after I post here for help.  Thanks...you are all swell.